# How do I match a number with regex in gsub and insert a value?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to replace a string like "`123456`" to "`,123456`".

I tried this.

```
address = address.gsub(/\d{6}/, "")
```

But I don't know how tell `gsub` to use the value matched to concatenate with "`,`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://blog.ethanvizitei.com/2010/06/using-regex-groups-for-rubys-gsub.html):

```
address.gsub /(\d{6})/, ',\1'
```

Comment: Unless the number is exactly six digits, you should probably use `/(\d+)/`. Remember, the OP said a string "like"....

Comment: True.  I was addressing the group capture problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
address.gsub! /^/, ','
```

Either you need only this or you are not showing enough context behind it.